# Python Complex IF Statement

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm getting some syntax error here and can't seem to find it:

```
if open_prices[0] > close_prices[0]:
  if (close_prices[0] - low_prices[0]) >= 2*(open_prices[0] - close_prices[0]) and          
     (high_pices[0] - open_prices[0]) <= 0.5*(open_prices[0] - close_prices[0]):
      x = 1
```

The error is

```
if (close_prices[0] - low_prices[0]) >= 2*(open_prices[0] - close_prices[0]) and (high_pices[0] - open_prices[0] <= 0.5*(open_prices[0] - close_prices[0]):
                                                                                                                                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Am I incorrect in the syntax or formatting?

Comment: Can you include the entire traceback? It will narrow down which line is failing and it has a handy hat `^` showing where it is confused.

Comment: Oh, there was a hat! `(high_pices[0] - open_prices[0] <= 0.5` is missing a closing paren.

Comment: Hi, there was no traceback.   Just stating the syntax error on line 100, and pointing at the IF statement..........

Comment: Whether you get a traceback or just the highlighting depends on the tool. I added the error message to the code block assuming that's what it looks like on the screen.

Comment: Your code has the same `if` condition repeated twice, and you fixed one missing parenthesis, but not another one in the copy of that line. Is that the actual error you're describing here? If so, don't remove it, that makes the question not make any sense at all! Fix it in your *actual* code, but not here.

Comment: Did adding the paren fix it? When pasting your code I also had an error on line 2 right after the `and` terminating the line. I'm not sure if your real code just strings that out into one super long line.

Comment: @Blckknght - I was a bit puzzled myself. I think that second one must have been part of the error message and edited the question to reflect that. I hope I got that right...

Comment: Several IDEs and text editors will automatically highlight matching pairs of parentheses for you, and/or offer a shortcut command to move the cursor from the opening parenthesis to its matching close parenthesis or vice-versa. You should use tools like this to make sure things are bracketed the way you expected them to be.

Answer (score 0):

you didn't close the `parenthesis` of 2nd `if` statement:

```
if open_prices[0] > close_prices[0]:
  if (close_prices[0] - low_prices[0]) >= 2*(open_prices[0] - close_prices[0]) and \          
     (high_pices[0] - open_prices[0]) <= 0.5*(open_prices[0] - close_prices[0]):
      x = 1

if (close_prices[0] - low_prices[0]) >= 2*(open_prices[0] - close_prices[0]) and (high_pices[0] - open_prices[0] <= 0.5*(open_prices[0] - close_prices[0])):
    pass
```

Note: also make sure in your first `if` statement while using line-break add a `\` after `and` else you will end up with `syntax error`

Comment: Many thanks everyone for your quick help!   Much appreciated!

Comment: if this answer served your purpose accept this one as correct answer. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your second if statement is wrongly structured. Python follows strict rules of indentation and throws a syntax error when it does not know what to do with a statement, here you've left one part hanging (the line ending with `and`), so it tries to parse it as a complete statement which obviously fails.

A simple fix would be to enclose the entire predicate inside parentheses (this makes it a single statement), like so:

```html
if ( (close_prices[0] - low_prices[0]) >= 2*(open_prices[0] - close_prices[0]) and         
     (high_pices[0] - open_prices[0]) <= 0.5*(open_prices[0] - close_prices[0]) ):
      x = 1
```